# Sublime Text 3: Joomla coding standard (PHP Code Sniffer) is not executed

Tags: php, development-tool

2 years ago I installed Joomla coding standard definition for PHP Codesniffer (https://github.com/joomla/coding-standards) for Sublime Text and everything worked well.

I just moved to a new laptop and set up a new development environment, now Joomla coding standard doesn't run when saving files.

Yes, PHP Code Sniffer was installed and works well. In my "Settings - User" I have

```
{
    "phpcs_additional_args": {
        "--standard": "Joomla",
        "-n": ""
    },
}
```

And this doesn't work. But if I change "Joomla" to "PSR2" then I get errors/warnings when saving files. So PHPCS works with PSR2 standard but not with Joomla standard.

If any developer here has any suggestion, please let me know. I really appreciate!

I use openSUSE 13.2 and Sublime Text 3.

This was how I installed Joomla standard, I assume it was successful :)

```
username@servername:~> sudo git clone https://github.com/joomla/coding-standards.git `pear config-get php_dir`/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/Joomla
root's password:
Cloning into '/usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/Joomla'...
remote: Counting objects: 1916, done.
remote: Total 1916 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1916
Receiving objects: 100% (1916/1916), 1.04 MiB | 117.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (727/727), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

I'm not sure if it is related, but I get errors when running from command line. Hadn't try this way before.

```
username@servername:~> phpcs --standard=Joomla /srv/www/htdocs/joomla341/
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHP_CodeSniffer_Exception' with message 'Class PHP_CodeSniffer_CommentParser_ClassCommentParser not found' in /usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/Joomla/Sniffs/Commenting/FileCommentSniff.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer.php(1318): include_once()
#1 /usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer.php(560): PHP_CodeSniffer->registerSniffs(Array, Array)
#2 /usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(830): PHP_CodeSniffer->initStandard(Array, Array)
#3 /usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(95): PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->process()
#4 /usr/bin/phpcs(25): PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->runphpcs()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/Joomla/Sniffs/Commenting/FileCommentSniff.php on line 18
```

Comment: What version of Code Sniffer are you using?

Comment: Hi @Lodder I'm not sure how to get the version, but I see in the comment block in /usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer/Sniff.php, it says "2.3.0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla conding standards are created for PHP CodeSniffer 1.5.x.

```
pear install PHP_CodeSniffer-1.5.x
```

For instance, just yestearday I installed the latest 1.5.6 in Ubuntu with:

```
pear install PHP_CodeSniffer-1.5.6
```

In addition, you may want to copy the files from the repo http://joomla.github.io/coding-standards to the local directory where they are located:

```
pear config-get php_dir
```

In my system, coding standards are located in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards

Ref: https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_CodeSniffer#Installation

Comment: Thank you @Anibal, I uninstalled PHPCS 2 and installed 1.5.6. I guess I run "pear install PHP_CodeSniffer" to the latest version was installed. But it was not enough yet, I needed to delete the folder /usr/share/php5/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/Joomla, and git clone again. Now every works. My bad to miss the "Important note" in the git repo :).